# Site_Prism not finding POM elements when page.find used

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

So I have setup a Capybara, Cucumber project with SitePrism for POM and for the most part it works. When I use:

```
Then('Find object name') do
expect(@page).to have_object_name
end
```

it works just fine but when I come to use:

```
Then('Assign object names text to a variable') do
expect(@page).to have_object_name
valueA = @page.find('object_name').text
end
```

this doesnt work and throws an error

```
Unable to find css "object_name" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

However, if I use:

```
Then('Assign object names text to a variable') do
expect(@page).to have_object_name
valueA = @page.find(:xpath, 'object_name_XPath').text
end
```

this works out just fine as well, but this sort of defeats the point of POM as it would greatly increase maintenance.

I assume I must be missing something to get the page.find locate the object_name from my page but I have danced around it and searched high and low but can't seem to figure the problem out.
Help? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@page.find` takes a CSS selector (by default - it's actually just the Capybara `find` method), not the name of a SitePrism `element`.

If @page is a `SitePrism::Page` or `SitePrism::Section` object and you have defined elements on it, then you just access that element as a method on `@page` - See https://github.com/natritmeyer/site_prism#accessing-the-individual-element

```
@page.object_name
```